# Capturing sound from TV Card with C#

Tags: c#, wpf, directx

I have written a WPF application which is capturing display and sound from TV Card from with through C# code. I can get the display from TV card, but I can't get any sound from TV Card. BTW, I'm using .NET framework 3.5 with  Visual Studio 2010. My question is how can I get the sound from the TV card?

Lastly, I tried  anything like below by using DirectSound library of DirectX. However, I got the following errors.

1. The best overloaded method match for
   `'Microsoft.DirectX.DirectSound.Device.SetCooperativeLevel(System.Windows.Forms.Control,
   Microsoft.DirectX.DirectSound.CooperativeLevel)'` has some invalid
   arguments.
2. Argument 1: cannot convert from `'Wpfvideo.MainWindow'` to
   `'System.Windows.Forms.Control'`

Code:

```
private DS.Device soundDevice;
private SecondaryBuffer buffer;
private ArrayList soundlist = new ArrayList();

private void InitializeSound()
{
     soundDevice = new DS.Device();
     soundDevice.SetCooperativeLevel(this, CooperativeLevel.Priority);

    BufferDescription description = new BufferDescription();
    description.ControlEffects = false;
    buffer = new SecondaryBuffer(CaptureDeviceName, description, soundDevice);
    buffer.Play(0, BufferPlayFlags.Default);
    SecondaryBuffer newshotsound = buffer.Clone(soundDevice);
    newshotsound.Play(0, BufferPlayFlags.Default);
}
```

Comment: You are getting the error because the SetCooperativeLevel method is expecting a windows forms control and you are passing it a WPF window.

Comment: thanks for your reply.What should I do?

Comment: There is no "fix" for that you cant turn a wpf window into a winforms control.

Comment: @Selo: Can you shed any light on this timeline? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105969/wheres-my-bounty-gone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var windowInteropHelper = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
soundDevice = new DS.Device();
soundDevice.SetCooperativeLevel(windowInteropHelper.Handle, CooperativeLevel.Priority);
```

Answer (score 0):

The call to `soundDevice.SetCooperativeLevel(...)` is expecting a winforms control as it's first parameter, and you're trying to give it a WPF window (which is not a winforms control).